# Windows phone Webbrowser bouncy behaviour

Tags: windows-phone

How to restrict the webbrowser control bouncy behaviour (white space is seen while scrolling up and down). Please refer the screenshot below.

[image: Webbrowser control of windows phone]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to disable the 'bounce in the WP7 or WP8 WebBrowser control.

But the issue you're seeing can be fixed with a small bit of CSS. Simply apply a `background-color` to the `BODY` of the document..

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {background: black}
        #content {background: black}
        p {color:white}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```