# Bouncing when overflow set to auto or scroll in WP8 WebBrowser control

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I know it is duplicate with this post, but there was not an acceptable solution.
[Windows phone Webbrowser bouncy behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517016/windows-phone-webbrowser-bouncy-behaviour)

"-ms-touch-action: none;" works smoothly util an element has the style of overflow with value auto or scroll. after the content scrolls to the top or bottom. if i put away my finger and back, and continue scrolling, the page bounces with my finger.

this issue would only happen in the control rather than the system browser, so I guess their should be a solution anyway?

Anyone gets a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

1. I created a plugin for this issue, check out https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-fix-wp-bouncing
2. It doesn't seem to work well if you want something like "pull down and release to refresh". For this purpose, I managed another solution but I will leave the code to yourself.
   Change `overflow-y` to `hidden` when it scrolls to top. Programmatically calculate `scrollTop` based on touch events and `preventDefault()`, toggle `overflow-y` between `hidden` and `auto` based on your **programmatically calculated `scrollTop`**. When the touch ends, simulate the inertia. Be sure to clear your timer at proper line.

## Original Answer

After tons of tempts, finally worked out an acceptable solution! I guess I would be the first one? But the bad news is, it's not a simple and easy-to-use one.

I read about an article discussing how to suppressing zoom and scroll interactions in WP7 [here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/11/17/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control.html), unfortunately it doesn't work that well in WP8 (Haven't tested WP7).

But even it works, it won't be what I want. Because I would want the overflow-auto-or-scroll elements to be able to scroll, without the bouncing effect which happens on whole page.

So here we got a way to suppress the scrolling but we need conditions. Here's the complete solution.

C# (another [LinqToVisualTree.cs](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2010/03/04/linq-to-visual-tree.html) file is required)

```
private void mainBrowser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var border = mainBrowser.Descendants<Border>().Last() as Border;
    border.ManipulationDelta += border_ManipulationDelta;
    border.ManipulationCompleted += border_ManipulationCompleted;
}

void border_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e) {
    mainBrowser.InvokeScript("onmanipulationcompleted");
}

void border_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e) {
    var status = mainBrowser.InvokeScript("onmanipulationdelta") as string;
    if (status == "top" || status == "both") {
        if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y > 0) {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    if (status == "bottom" || status == "both") {
        if (e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y < 0) {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

JS

```
window.manipulationTarget = null;

window.onmanipulationdelta = function () {
    if (!window.manipulationTarget) {
        return '';
    }

    var target = window.manipulationTarget;

    var top = target.scrollTop == 0;
    var bottom = target.scrollTop + target.clientHeight == target.scrollHeight;

    return top ? bottom ? 'both' : 'top': bottom ? 'bottom' : '';
};

window.onmanipulationcompleted = function () {
    window.manipulationTarget = null;
};

// and you'll need to make calls to every elements
// with overflow auto or scroll with this:
function preventBouncing(ele) {
    // using jQuery.
    ele.on('MSPointerDown pointerdown', function (e) {
        window.manipulationTarget = this;
    });
}
```

It doesn't look good but works well. And good luck people who stuck on this for so long a time~

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I used a variation of this approach with my Cordova (3.4) app, and it works great at preventing the bounce when you're already at the top/bottom of the page. It doesn't stop the bounce on inertia, but I'm not sure there's any good solution to that. Note: I put more of the scroll/no scroll logic in JS than you did. Happy to share my code if folks would like to see it.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'd love to see your work around. BTW for me the -ms-touch-action has already suppressed the inertial bouncing, though I do notice that sometimes this or my solution won't work. But it rarely happens and I haven't figured out the pattern.

Comment: I filed a bug on Cordova with some details and code snippets here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6231. I haven't tried ms-touch-action yet; but won't that prevent scrolling altogether?

Comment: hope they would make a built-in fix, though i am not using it yet, haha. and no, that won't prevent scrolling (set it for selector "html" only, if you want the entire page to be able to scroll, you may need to add another container for that). :D